# Single github repo for multiple platforms

Tags: git, github, npm, pip, luarocks

I am writing a small code project (or module), and willing to implement the same technique in 3 different languages, namely: Python, JS, Lua. I would like to make a single github repo that contains all the code in all these languages.

My question is: How do I make this as an installable package, that works for all three languages? i.e:

For Python, I would like it to be available via

```
pip install packagex
```

For Lua, I would like it to be available via:

```
luarocks install packagex
```

And similarly for JS/Node:

```
npm install packagex
```

Yes, I can create three different repos for three different platforms and register each one of them as installable packages, but I would like to keep everything in a single source repo. How should I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: GitHub is merely a repository for source code, and there is no reason why, for example, a Python project could not be in the same repository as a JavaScript project.  How you go about creating your installer is a different story.

Comment: Yep. Everything can be practically contained in a single repository. The issue of creating the installer.

Comment: Three branches in one repo could hold all your code. But I don't think the installation issue is Git's business.

Comment: There is a good discussion of this in [this existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679614/whats-the-best-practice-for-putting-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository). You could also put each language in a different directory in the root level of your repo.

Comment: Yes, a single repository with three directories can be a way to go. But when creating the installer for each, maybe I will have to pass the source address differently.

Comment: **Continous Integration**

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the LuaRocks part of the question:

### LuaRocks

If you choose to create subdirectories for each language and the Lua stuff lives under `/lua`, you can follow the [usual process of creating a rockspec file](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Creating-a-rock), and add a `source.dir` entry, telling it to work within the subdirectory. So, in the above link's example, you'do something like:

```
source = {
   url = "git://github.com/me/luafruits",
   tag = "v1.0",
   dir = "luafruits/lua"
}
```

`source.dir` is documented along with the rest of the [rockspec format](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Rockspec-format):

> - source.dir (string) - the name of the directory created when the source archive is unpacked. Can be omitted if it can be inferred from the source.file field. Example: "luasocket-2.0.1"

For Git repositories, `source.dir` is inferred by default to be the last component of the path, but you can redefine it at will if your code lives in a subdirectory. All other paths in the rockspec will be relative to this `source.dir`.

**Alternatively**, you could just add `lua/` to all paths of your `build` section instead. In the "luafruits" example from the documentation, notice that all sources live inside `src/`. Just use `lua/` instead and you're good to go, no need to use `source.dir`.