# Pushing separate projects into larger team repo

Tags: git, github

I have a few projects, Project 1, Project 2, and Project 3, all in their seperate repos.

My team is now setting up on github. Within our larger organization, it seems like what other teams have been doing is creating one big repo to host various projects.

How do I set up a repo with a folder called Project 1, and push Project 1 into there?

Comment: This topic is one that has been closed as off-topic before. Both for being opinionated (about monolith vs separate repos) and for asking for a guide or other online resource. Look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679614/whats-the-best-practice-for-putting-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository) QnA and see if you can get some hints. Also, question the need for monolith repos. If projects are released seperatly I can personally see no valid reason for having a monolith.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use different branches for different projects if those are not related/dependent. In case you have to use same *repo*, you can use **orphan branches**. These are independent branches and do not share histories which is your requirement.

Also check this answer: [What's the best practice for putting multiple projects in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14679614/5746903)