# One git repo for Android+web service

Tags: git, github, git-repo

How can we use a single git repository for Android application + web service back-end ? Generally its done separately  . But its mandatory for us to use a single repository and our contribution to be shown .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in one repo. This could be achieved by just putting everything into one folder or (recommended way) put everything in dedicated, Independent branches (alias orphan branches).

A good explanation with examples is given in [this post's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679614/whats-the-best-practice-for-putting-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository)

To learn more about orphan branches, I recommend this [article on bugfactory.io](https://bugfactory.io/blog/orphaned-brachnes-in-git/)

Edit: Fixed Typo