# Add multiple apps with their own git in a git repo

Tags: git, github

I want to add backend and frontend in the same git repo as this one

https://github.com/panacloud-modern-global-apps/full-stack-serverless-cdk/tree/main/step06_appsync_frontend_amplify

When I try to push an app it gives an error, So I have to remove the git from the frontend and backend both. And Have it in the parent one only.

Error

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    Backend/
    frontend/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Could you share the error as well?

Comment: Why not just use two different repos?

Comment: I have updated the error.

Comment: I want to keep frontend and backend of one app in the same repo

Comment: Why don'y you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931761/working-with-git-and-multiple-projects/7931825#7931825

Comment: There is no error shown above.

Comment: submodules works thank